# Is it possible for a database to be impenetrable?

Tags: databases

I was wondering if it is possible to create some sort of database that is physically impossible to enter. While creating it, you store some information in it and program it to spit that information after a period of time. But not even you can access it even if you wanted to, you have no choice but to wait.

Comment: _"after a period of time"_ - Time is not a simple thing... How will the database know what time it is? If you get time updates from an external time server, somebody could intercept that traffic and fool the database. If you don't use an external time server, you have a risk of the database time being wrong. But that depends on how accurate you need the time to be and how long you're planning on keeping it secret.

Comment: I think you might be interested in a [data diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidirectional_network)

Comment: Well, I meant the timer would be inside the code (running constantly).

Answer (score 1):

Security is complex, it's not just a matter of setting a timer and you'll be sure nobody can access the information in advance.

Even if your code was completely secure, your code runs on a server that might have some vulnerabilities. There might be vulnerabilities or weaknesses in the web server (Apache, Nginx, etc.), in the database software (MySQL, MariaDB, etc.), in the OS (Linux, Windows, etc.) in the machine (Intel, AMD, etc.), in your physical environment (your hosting provider's facilities or wherever you keep your servers, etc.), etc.

So yes, you can write a perfectly secure line of code that does what you want, or you can write a perfectly secure piece of software if you are skilled enough, but you won't have full control over the whole infrastructure and environment. That's why you can never really say you are "impenetrable", unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

Actually there are already devices close to what you need. Take some HSM that fits FIPS-142 Level 4, has an embedded timer and a power cell. Program it so that it displays some data at particular time. Level 4 means that it will destroy all the data when it detects penetration.